# WIRIS & tinymce 4. Inline method

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Anyone has fixed wiris plugin to work with tinymce 4 inline method?

Already customized it to work with tinymce 4, but still not working with inline method.

Anyone fixed this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are sorry that you have needed to do the WIRIS integration for TinyMCE 4.x yourself, our latest beta release already supports TinyMCE 4.x. It is available at http://www.wiris.com/plugins/download.beta.

Unfortunately, there is a bug using the inline method. We are currently working on it.

Edit: Our latest version available at the link above now supports TinyMCE inline method.

Comment: Hadn't noticed the TinyMCE 4.x beta plugin...

However i just replaced with beta plugin and i'm getting errors from service.php & createimage.php :(

````uncaught exception: file_put_contents(/var/www/applications/data/plugins/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/lib/com/wiris/plugin/web/../../../../../../formulas/b608c0ffa0d0b54b3f791a41c9c2708a.ini): failed to open stream: Permission denied (errno: 2) in /var/www/applications/data/plugins/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wiris/integration/lib/sys/io/File.class.php at line #12````

Comment: Please make sure you're not using the configuration.ini you had before updating to the beta and check the permissions in your plugin cache and formulas directories (`/var/www/applications/data/plugins/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wi‌​ris/integration/cache` and `/var/www/applications/data/plugins/tinymce/plugins/tiny_mce_wi‌​ris/integration/formulas`) . The web server user needs to have write permissions over those directories. Alternatively you can change their default location in the configuration.ini file (editing `wiriscachedirectory` and `wirisformuladirectory`).

Comment: It was permission problem. I had only changed permission for the integration directory & forgot cache & formulas directories. It's working now :). Hope inline method will also be soon available...

Thank you for WIRIS plugin. The best math plugin i've tried.

Comment: Hello. Anything new for the inline method?

Comment: Our latest plugin version available at the link in the original reply includes support for the inline method.